# use of GCKDeviceProvider from Google-cast-sdk

Tags: google-cast-sdk

Use of `GCKDeviceProvider` in google-cast-sdk.

How to get the list of already discovered device?
Can we store the discovered device list from google-cast-sdk in NSUserDefault, to use it in for app background to foreground handling?